# Python - Poloniex trading api problems

Tags: python, api, python-requests, urllib

Despite the number of posts regarding Poloniex / Python trading api access, I still can't figure out how to make this work on Python 3.6. Here is one version which, in my view, should word perfectly, but doesn't:

```
req['command'] = 'requestBalances'
req['nonce'] = int(time.time() * 1000)
post_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(req).encode('utf-8')
hmac_key = self.Secret.encode('utf-8')

sign = hmac.new(hmac_key, post_data, hashlib.sha512)
sign = sign.hexdigest()

 headers = {
    'Sign': sign,
     'Key': self.APIKey
  }

  res = requests.post('https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', data=post_data, headers=headers)
```

If I run the above, with the correct api / secret codes, I get an "invalid command" error.

Interestingly, if I replace the requests.post function with :

```
req = urllib.request.Request(url='https://poloniex.com/tradingApi', data=post_data, headers=headers)
res = urllib.request.urlopen(req,timeout=5)
```

then I don't get an error, but just an empty bytes array (after res.read())

Any tips on how to make this work would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share the full traceback you are receiving?

Comment: By pure luck, I managed to find a solution. See the answer below

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to include:

```
"Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

in the header, i.e. :

```
headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    'Sign': sign,
    'Key': self.APIKey
}
```

Strangely, none of the other solutions I have seen has included this additional field, but there we go.

PS. the alternative using urllib.request still just returns an empty byte string.